# Inequality involving circumradii

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, triangles, geometric-inequalities

Let $ABC$ be a triangle and $M$ a point on the side $BC$. Let $R_1$,$R_2$, and $R$ be the circumradii of the triangles $ABM, ACM$, and $ABC$. Show that $\max\{R_1,R_2\} \geq R\cos\frac A 2$.

Comment: Change $>$ into $ \geq $ (consider the case of the isosceles right triangle)

Answer (score 0):

In $\Delta ABC$ we have:
$$\frac{a}{\sin A}=2R$$
$\Rightarrow 2R\cdot\sin A=a\Rightarrow2R(2\sin\frac{A}{2}\cdot\cos\frac{A}{2})=a
\Rightarrow R\cdot\cos\frac{A}{2}=\dfrac{1}{4}\cdot\dfrac{a}{\sin\frac{A}{2}}$

Now assume $AM$ divides $\angle A$ into $\angle A_1$ and $\angle A_2$, also consider
$|\alpha|\lt\dfrac{A}{2}\lt 90^\circ$

$\max\{R_1,R_2\}\ge\dfrac{1}{2}(R_1+R_2)=\dfrac{1}{4}(\dfrac{BM}{\sin A_1}+\dfrac{CM}{\sin A_2})\ge\dfrac12(\dfrac{BM+CM}{\sin A_1+\sin A_2})$

$=\dfrac12\cdot\dfrac{a}{\sin(\frac{A}{2}-\alpha)+\sin(\frac{A}{2}+\alpha)}
\ge \dfrac12\cdot\dfrac{a}{2\sin\frac{A}{2}\cos\alpha}\ge\dfrac14\cdot\dfrac{a}{\sin\frac{A}{2}}=R\cdot\cos\frac{A}{2}$

---

P.S: Proof of the used inequality: Suppose $a=\sin A_1$, $b=BM$, $c=\sin A_2$, $d=CM$ $(b,d,b+d\neq0)$

By using [Chebyshev's sum inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality) (since $\sin A_1\ge\sin A_2 \equiv BM\ge CM$) on the third step we have:

$\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{c}{d}=\dfrac{ad+bc}{bd}\ge\dfrac{(a+c)(b+d)}{2bd}
=\dfrac{(a+c)(b+d)^2}{(b+d)\cdot2bd}=\dfrac{(a+c)(b^2+d^2+2bd)}{(b+d)\cdot2bd}
\ge\dfrac{(a+c)\cdot4bd}{(b+d)\cdot2bd}=2\cdot\dfrac{a+c}{b+d}$

Comment: Thank you very much. It's a very interesting solution.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: How can you prove that $\frac a b + \frac c d >= 2* \frac {a+b} {c+d}$? You used it in your proof.

Comment: Right, I added the proof to the solution.

Comment: I don't know Cauchy's inequality. CAn you help me?

Comment: Of course, and I made a mistake about the name, it's called Chebysev ineqaulity! I added a link to it. but where is the problem text gone?

Comment: THE INITIAL QUESTION IS ALMOST COMPLETELY ERASED and replaced by something that is a kind of "cut and paste error", a single unfinished sentence "Let ABC be a triangle with sides a,b,c, and p semiperimeter" where I don't even find back the beginning of the old question. Is it consecutive to the edit that has been made 4 hours ago ?

Comment: @JeanMarie My bad, I accidentaly tried to edit it. Can you help me?

Comment: @Imawesome You can tell me if there's still something not clear indeed.

Comment: @Amir Naseri Everything is correct except of the inequality. I wonder if there is another way to prove it.

Comment: I searched a little but didn't find another, is there something wrong with this one? the properties in which we are able to use Chebyshev's sum inequality are satisfied, so I thought it might be fine.